# Angular PatchValue of nested arrays

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-reactive-forms

I Want to patch a value of an array inside another array, I can achieve it by using

`this.myForm.value.array1[index1].array2[index2].type = type;`

although it doesn't update the forms value on the screen only in the form values in code, I the code below to patch values in the first array and it updates the values on the screen i just cant write it to be able to reach the second array

`(<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['array1']).at(index1).get("type").patchValue(type);`

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you not use setValue, Angular change the value but Angular not reflect in the input, don't mark the input as touched...

So

```
((this.myForm.get('array1') as FormArray)
       .at(index1).get('array2') as FormArray)
       .at(index2).get("type").patchValue(type);
```

or

```
this.form.get('array1.'+index1+'.array2.'+index2+'.type').patchValue(type)
```

NOTE1: using get to access at element of an array is the way `array1.index`, so `array1.0` get the first element of the array, `array1.1` the second one...

NOTE2: is recomended use the method get(name) vs controls[name]

**Update** I don't know yours requeriments, but If you want simple control an array of arrays of an object you can use a FormArray of FormArrays of FormGroup.

Well, some like

```
formArray=new FormArray([
      new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
           type:new FormControl('uno')
        }),
        new FormGroup({
           type:new FormControl('dos')
        }),
      ]),
      new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
           type:new FormControl('tres')
        }),
        new FormGroup({
           type:new FormControl('cuatro')
        }),
      ])
    ])
```

Can be mannage in an html as

```
<div *ngFor="let array of formArray.controls">
  <div *ngFor="let group of array.controls" [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="type">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case use

```
(this.form.at(0) as FormArray).at(1).get('type').patchValue('new');
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfkcns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Nice technique @Eliseo ! for me it worked without the `as FormArray`. Something like:

`this.myForm.get('array1').at(index1).get('array2').at(index2).get("type").patchValue(type);`

Comment: @VitaeAliquam, it's a old post (Ive learn some about Angular since time), You can concatenate string in function get, so you can use some like:`this.myForm.get('array1.'+index1+'.array2.'+index2+'.type').patchValue(type)`